# what is the best algorithm to search an array for a bit pattern using bitwise AND?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, bitwise-operators

The problem is to count number of integers in array t[] that satisfy the condition: 
a & t[i] = a
where '&' is the bitwise and operator and a is a given integer.
I may solve the same problem for different a.
Let's say I have to solve the problem for Q queries: each query is an integer a.
Is there any solution better than the O(Q x n) one? (n is the size of t[] )

Comment: Great...I have a solution then..

Comment: Interesting question with a boring title: maybe change it so that other users might recognize the issue. For example: "what is the best algorithm to search an array for a bit pattern using bitwise AND?"

Answer (score 0):

Not in the worst case, if you choose the inputs right you can arrange to have the entire `t` be your answer every time.

But you can do usually do better.

Put all of `t` in a bit-trie. A query is just a traversal through the trie, where at level `k` you process the 0-child only iff the `k`th bit of `a` is 0. All the leafs reached this way have the property that they have a 0 only in those bit positions where `a` also has a zero, which means that they satisfy
`a & value == a`.

Comment: The cost to build the trie must be included

Comment: So , what will be the overall complexity ? O(n + log(n) * Q) ?

Comment: @GhazouaniMedamine O(Qn) plus an additional O(n) preprocessing. That looks worse that it was before, but that's because of output sensitivity. In terms of the output it's O(total returned items over all queries) with still O(n) preprocessing.